# What is the .psess file in my Windows Service?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010, .net-4.0, windows-services

I've been making changes to a Windows Service in Visual Studio (2010, .NET 4.0 project) and when I go to close the solution or commit to TFS, Visual Studio prompts me to save a .psess file (MyService.psess) that I've never seen before and does not seem to exist yet (a file save dialog pops up prompting me for a location).

I can't find any documentation on this file.  What is it?  What might I have done to create it?  Is it required?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

These files generally contain [performance profiling](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182371.aspx) session data. You can view the [Performance Explorer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc470664.aspx) window to see if you have any open sessions using the menu View->Other Windows->Performance Explorer.

You can delete the sessions there also, if need be.

Answer (score 8):

It's a Microsoft Visual Studio performance session file and contains information about a performance test session.